# adwhirl house ads for iPad

Tags: ipad, adwhirl

I have an app in which I show advertisement and to do so I'm using adWhirl. But my app is universal. I found out how to show iAd and Admob there, but I also need to show house ads. I'm looking for a solution of showing house ads for iPad using adWhirl. Does anybody have any idea how to manage that?

Answer (score 0):

AdWhirl only supports mediation using the 320x50 format.  However, AdMob recently came out with a [Mediation](https://support.google.com/admob/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2413211&topic=2403413&ctx=topic) solution that can solve this use case.  You can mediate with tablet-sized formats as well as house ads.